# Binding textboxes inside a usercontrol to datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Is the way that I'm binding the UserControl to the DataGrid correct? 
In my MainWindow I have a datagrid (code below):

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="MusicListGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MusicList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Artist" Binding="{Binding Artist,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Album" Binding="{Binding Album,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Track" Binding="{Binding Track,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The usercontrol inside my MainWindow, that I'm binding to the selected item of the datagrid:

DataTemplate(in MainWindow):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MusicDetailListTemplate"  >
        <v:MusicDetailView DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MusicListGrid,Path=SelectedItem}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

ContentControl(in MainWindow):

```
<ContentControl x:Name="musicDetail" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MusicDetailListTemplate}" Grid.Column="1" />
```

The textboxes inside my UserControl looks like this:

```
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="200" Margin="10,5" Text="{Binding Artist,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="200" Margin="10,5" Text="{Binding Album,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width="200" Margin="10,5" Text="{Binding Track,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

This works, but I'm not sure if I'm doing the correct way? 
Can I also bind a textbox to the datagrid like this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Path=MusicListGrid.Artist.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"  />
```

The data in the datagrid is an `ObservableCollection<Music>` (music is my model).

If I replace my UserControl with a tabcontrol, should I have the tabcontrol be a separate view or just be part of MainWindow? And have the content of the tabcontrol be separate views? I was thinking of having the datagrid and a tabcontrol with 2 tabs, one for editing and the other for displaying (to look more presentable).

Sorry if these are very basic questions, I just want to be on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

It is more common to set the `Content` property of the `ContentControl` element to the data object:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="musicDetail" Content="{Binding ElementName=MusicListGrid, 
    Path=SelectedItem}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MusicDetailListTemplate}" />
```

The `DataContext` defines what the data of the relevant type should look like in the UI, so you shouldn't really set the `DataContext` there... it is automatically set to the relevant data object instance... it should look more like this (where `Prefix` is the XML Namespace Prefix that you set up for your project and `YourClass` is the type of object in the `DataGrid`):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MusicDetailListTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Prefix:YourClass}">
        <v:MusicDetailView DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```